# Image not appearing in UIImageView

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uiimageview

I have a `UIImageView` in Interface Builder connected to an outlet called imageView. The statement

```
[imageView setImage: [UIImage imageNamed: @"xxxx.png"]];
```

displays an image successfully if placed in `viewDidLoad`, but NOT if placed in an action method in the same view controller. There's an `NSLog` in the action method so I know it's firing.

I've looked at the other "`UIImageView` not appearing" questions but none of them seem directly relevant. Any help would be much appreciated!

Thanks,

Mark

Comment: have you tried  : [self.view addSubview:imageView]; ?

Answer (score 2):

Try forcing a redraw:

```
[imageView setNeedsDisplay];
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to help. I should have made clear that even if the setImage statement in viewDidLoad is commented out, the corresponding statement in the action method has no effect. So I don't think it has anything to do with an image already being in the view. - Mark